# Tkinter label text is a funtion object instead of text

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been googling around for over an hour at this point, but I can't figure this out. I want to display the result of the function as the label's text. The problem is that even though the return of the function is for example: 250.2, when I place the label into the tkinter window, it looks more like (numbers)< lambda >, which I think is a function object.

The label:

```
self.temperature = ttk.Label(
            self,
            text=lambda:self.displayInfo(0))
```

The function:

```
def displayInfo(self, index):
        self.infoList = WeatherInfo.jsonToString(self)
        
        return self.infoList[index]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `lambda` where a string is expected.  If you want the result of the function, then just call the function:

```
self.temperature = ttk.Label( self, text=self.displayInfo(0) )
```

Comment: If I don't have the lambda there, it calls the function too early, and the program fails because the function lacks information. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, if I remove the lambda and remove the parentheses, the result is basically the same, a bunch of numbers followed by the name of the function.

Comment: The `text` parameter is immediate.  If you don't have a value when you create the label, then give it a dummy value, and use `self.temperature.config( text=self.displayInfo(0))` later to change it.